# How to mock a hbaseadmin without creating actual connection

Tags: hbase

I am new to Hadoop. I have written a Java class implementing hbase configuration and hbaseadmin.createtable method. I want to test this using powermock but when I try to mock the method call it is trying to create actual connection and I am getting failure to login error. Any ideas how to mock test tableexists method.

```
Mainclass{

  Public static Boolean tableexists(string table)
  {
    //Code logic with hbaseadmin intialization
  }

  //Other code
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
exception occured in tablesExists methodfailure to login java.io.IOException: failure to login at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:841
```

Comment: i am getting this error:

Comment: exception occured in tablesExists methodfailure to login
java.io.IOException: failure to login
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:841)